# add_actions called from functions.php not returning good values

Tags: wp-query, actions

I am trying to add some security/acccess prevention to my site via the functions.php.  However whenever I try to add through functions.php (instead of as a plugin, which I've done in the past) it fails (always returns false). For example:

```
add_action("parse_query", checkaccess());  // in functions.php
```

and

```
function checkaccess() {
    $allowAccess = false;

    if(is_admin()||is_front_page()||is_home()||current_user_can('administrator'))
        $allowAccess=true;

    if($allowAccess)
        echo 'whatup'; //do something here

}
```

even if i try something basic - eg `global $wp_query; var_dump($wp_query);` I can't get the query var, its all NULL.  Any advice?  Is there some kind of walled sandbox the fuctions.php file operates from that it can't get any of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_action` should be:

```
add_action( "parse_query", "checkaccess" );
```

Comment: ah! in quotes rather than calling a function directly, right?

Comment: @dama_do_bling correct, callbacks should be string-formatted.